# how to get the value from associative array

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an array using array_push in php and I got

```
[0] => nithya.sreeraman 
[1] => jaivignesh.parthiban 
[2] => aadhil.ahmed 
[3] => aarthe.sathyanaraya 
[4] => abdulamjad.babu 
[5] => khaja.hussain 
[6] => abdulwahab.mohamed 
[7] => abdullasha.pari 
[8] => abinaya.sambandam 
[9] => abinesh.pugazhendhi
```

I want to collect the value as

```
('nithya.sreeraman','jaivignesh.parthiban','aadhil.ahmed',etc)
```

Is it possible in php I wnt to collect this value for `where column in` QUERY

Comment: use array_values() function

Comment: If you want it to use for whereIn Or select in both case you can pass the above array

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array_map(function($v) { return "'{$v}'"; }, $array);
echo "(" . implode(",", $array) . ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode` by comma and `str_replace`

```
$arr = [0 => 'nithya.sreeraman', 1 => 'jaivignesh.parthiban'];
$string = "('". str_replace(",", "','", implode(',', $arr))."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use php join

```
$array = array_map(function($x) { return "'" . $x . "'"; }, $array);
echo "(" . join(',', $array) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use  implode function to convert comma separated string

```
$final_output = "('" . implode("','", $your_input_array) . "')";
```

Comment: `implode()` works the same regardless if the array is indexed or associative, so there's no need for `array_values()` at all.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to run a **foreach loop** to get the values -

```
$name = array([0] => nithya.sreeraman [1] => jaivignesh.parthiban [2] => aadhil.ahmed 
[3] => aarthe.sathyanaraya [4] => abdulamjad.babu [5] => khaja.hussain 
[6] => abdulwahab.mohamed [7] => abdullasha.pari [8] => abinaya.sambandam 
[9] => abinesh.pugazhendhi);

$i = 0;
// Loop through assoc name array
foreach($name as $key => $value){
    $arrName[$i] = $value;
    $i++;
}
```

Your names will be stored in **$arrName**.

I hope this is what you were looking for :)